# How to add cardapio to panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, cardapio

I followed the instructions shown for downloading (I'm on Maverick) at the launchpad site for this main menu replacement:

https://launchpad.net/cardapio

It indicates that once you do this, it should show up in the Add to Panel list of applets, but I'm not seeing it. This is the first time I've installed a new applet; do I need to restart my session to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either restart your session or just issue 
`pkill gnome-panel`.
That will restart your panel(s) and then cardapio will be visible. Good choice by the way. I'm using it and it's a realy good replacement for gnome-do plus any menu.